# How to use GET variable as value in HTML hidden field?

Tags: php

Description: Create a PHP file, "delete-wish-form.php", with a form that has the following fields: - wishId (hidden field) The value of this field should be equal to a GET variable that is passed in via the url. So if the URL is delete-wish-form.php?wishId=1 then your hidden field looks like this: <input type="hidden>

Problem: I want to print value(hidden field) of GET variable using URL of delete-wish-form.php, my process-wish-form.php isn't able to read it.

[This is the delete-wish-form.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywLvw.png)

```
<form class="" action="process-delete-wish-form.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="wishId" value="<?php $wishId ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

[This is the process-wish-form.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeSfO.png)

```
<?php
$wishId = $_GET["wishId"];
echo $wishId;
 ?>
```

Comment: Why did you post images  of code instead of real code?

Comment: @funkFortyNiner Sorry, I added the code.

Comment: Have a look at your HTML source. If it doesn't reveal anything for it, then you have issues elsewhere. Enable error reporting also which helps.

Comment: is this `<?php echo($wishId) ?>` valid? Have it value? What is address in your browser after form submitting? (copy and paste, don't write, you can of course change the domain if you want stay anonymous)

Comment: @biesior before submitting the form is : http://localhost/Web%20Programming/Wishes/delete-wish-form.php?wishId=11

Comment: @biesior after submittihg the form is the http://localhost/Web%20Programming/Wishes/process-delete-wish-form.php?wishId=

Comment: so as you can see your `$wishId` is empty before submitting as you having `?wishId=` in the URL after submit, check why

Comment: @biesior Sir, I don't understand, why, I already checked, I want that when i add               
 ?wishId=12 at the end of the url it should echo me 12 in process-delete-wish-form.php

Comment: Show us WHOLE  `delete-wish-form.php` (from very beginning to very last char) and don't call me _sir_, we're not in army.

Comment: show us the whole code in the delete-wish-form.php file as @besior said

Comment: @ClementSam Whole code is in the question

Comment: So where are you getting the `$wishId` from in your delete-wish-form.php??

Answer (score -1):

If you are setting variable `$wishId` in delete-wish-form.php the issue is that you aren't echoing.
delete-wish-form.php should be something like

```
<?php
$wishId = $_GET["wishId"];
?>

...

<form class="" action="process-delete-wish-form.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="wishId" value="<?php echo $wishId ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

CAVEAT: trusting anything that is user input, like $_GET and $_POST, without sanitizing is bad. There should be logic to verify that $wishId is reasonable or expected value.

Answer (score -1):

Just shooting in your `delete-wish-form.php` before you try to `<?php echo $wishId ?>` you don't get the `$_GET['wishId']`, so try somewhere before:

```php
<?php $wishId = $_GET['wishId']; ?>
```

or if it's really whole code just:

```php
<form class="" action="process-delete-wish-form.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="wishId" value="<?php echo $_GET['wishId']; ?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that `$_GET` parameters are not parsed automatically to variables.

Note 2: for security reasons you should cast it to an integer, especially before doing SQL queries like

```php
$wishId = intval($_GET['wishId']);
```